# SQL query to populate index field based on groups

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to sql and was hoping that someone can help me with an update query. I have a users table with group_id (foreign key), user_id and user_index columns. There are multiple users corresponding to each individual group_id, and user_id is a serial column which goes from 1 to the table size.

I'm looking for a query that will update the user_index column so that, for each group_id, each user will have a unique, sequential index starting with 1. So within group 1 there would be user_index 1,2,3... and within group 2 there would be user_index 1,2,3... and so on. Here is an example to clarify:

Initial state:

```
user_id | group_id | user_index
1         1          0
2         1          0
3         1          0
4         2          0
5         3          0
6         3          0
```

Desired state:

```
user_id | group_id | user_index
1         1          1
2         1          2
3         1          3
4         2          1
5         3          1
6         3          2
```

I hope that's clear. This would be easy to do in C or C++, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it in sql.

Comment: do the user_ids that comprise a group always form an unbroken sequence?  Or could group_id=4 be user_id IN ( 7, 8, 20 ) for example?

Comment: They aren't an unbroken sequence, often there are some missing due to rows being deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableName
SET user_index = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TableName t2 
   WHERE t2.group_id = TableName.group_id AND t2.user_id <= TableName.user_id)
```

---

EDIT:
After looking at author's comment I created a test to see is this the right solution. Here's the test:

```
CREATE TABLE #table (user_id int, group_id int, user_index int)

INSERT INTO #table VALUES (1, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO #table VALUES (2, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO #table VALUES (3, 1, 0)
INSERT INTO #table VALUES (4, 2, 0)
INSERT INTO #table VALUES (5, 3, 0)
INSERT INTO #table VALUES (6, 3, 0)

SELECT * FROM #table

UPDATE #table
SET user_index = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #table t2 
WHERE t2.group_id = #table.group_id AND t2.user_id <= #table.user_id)

SELECT * FROM #table

DROP TABLE #table
```

The output of two selects are exactly the same as in author's two selects - the first as beginning state, and the second as the desired outcome.

Comment: This seems to update user_index with the number of users in that user's group (eg. if there are 12 users in group 1, user_index is set to 12 for each of those users). I'll look more into it, though.

Comment: No, if you look closer to the other part of WHERE clause, it sets it to the count of users in the same group that have user_id <= user_id of the row it's updating. The user with smallest ID in the group has 1 for the value of that count, the next smallest gets the value 2 and so on.

Comment: When I ran the query, it updated user_index with the total number of users in each group as I mentioned. It seems like it's quite close, but it isn't giving the desired results yet.

Comment: I tested it with code that I've put in the answer (it didn't fit here) and the result was the same as your desired outcome.

Comment: I tried your example as well, and it definitely works with the sample data that I provided. My actual data is a bit more complicated and I'm still having some problems getting it to work, but I should be able to get it working based on what you suggested. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help to you!