# SQL set index field based on date field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm hoping to achieve something similar to [SQL query to populate index field based on groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764849/sql-query-to-populate-index-field-based-on-groups).

The only difference is that I want to set the index field based on an existing date field.

My table structure is:

```
Product
-------
Group
Name
DateCreated
DisplayIndex
```

So I need to group by "Group" and update the DisplayIndex of items within that group based on their DateCreated date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;with C as
(
  select DisplayIndex,
         row_number() over (partition by [Group] order by DateCreated desc) as rn
  from Product 
)
update C set
  DisplayIndex = rn
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `row_number` to number rows per `Group`:

```
update  p
set     DisplayIndex = pn.rn
from    Product p
join    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by [Group] 
                                   order by DateCreated desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Product
        ) as pn
on      p.[Group] = pn.[Group]
        and p.[Name] = pn.[Name]
```

[Example on SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112049/)